# How to set multiple reminders in android for user specified times

Tags: android, service, reminders

I am using the below linked tutorial to set reminders. I was successful in setting a single reminder but for multiples ones, it still needs some tweaks.

http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

I have passed a `notification_id` and a `notificationText` to the function `setAlarmForNotification` along with each new request for reminder (to uniquely identify them) but it seems they all are getting replaced by the last reminder. And interestingly, the `notification_id` and `notificationText` being printed in the logcat are of the first reminder.

**NotifyService.java**

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

//Text string of the notification
private String notificationText;

/**
 * Class for clients to access
 */
public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    NotifyService getService() {
        return NotifyService.this;
    }
}

// Unique id to identify the notification.
//private static final int NOTIFICATION = 123;
// Name of an intent extra we can use to identify if this service was started to create a notification
public static final String INTENT_NOTIFY = "com.blundell.tut.service.INTENT_NOTIFY";
// The system notification manager
private NotificationManager mNM;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("NotifyService", "onCreate()");
    mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

    notificationText = intent.getStringExtra("notification_text");
    int notiId = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("notification_id"));

    // If this service was started by out AlarmTask intent then we want to show our notification
    if(intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false))
        showNotification(notiId);


    // We don't care if this service is stopped as we have already delivered our notification
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

// This is the object that receives interactions from clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

/**
 * Creates a notification and shows it in the OS drag-down status bar
 */
private void showNotification(int notiId) {
    // This is the 'title' of the notification
    CharSequence title = "Alarm!!";
    // This is the icon to use on the notification
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_card_giftcard_white_24dp;
    // This is the scrolling text of the notification
    CharSequence text = "Your notification time is upon us.";
    // What time to show on the notification
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);


    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    //notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_white_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(notificationText);

    notification = builder.build();

    // Clear the notification when it is pressed
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;



    // Send the notification to the system.
    mNM.notify(notiId, notification);

    // Stop the service when we are finished
    stopSelf();

}
```

}

What should be changed to make it work correct?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all your alarms are working, but if you check `NotifyService,java` it has the field

```
 private static final int NOTIFICATION = 123;
```

This means when each of your separate alarms triggers, they will start the service but the notification they produce will always have the same ID.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. **If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.**

---

To fix this, you would want to make that ID not a constant. Perhaps pass the ID in the intent extra's, you can take a hint of how to do that with the same way `intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);` is done inside the `AlarmTask`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've already taken care of this. I've added that part of my code to the question.

Comment: Added the whole class.

Comment: you are using a deprecated constructor and I'm not sure what version of Android device/emu you are using, so that could effect it, see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#Notification.Builder(android.content.Context)

Comment: Android Studio isn't showing me any deprecation. And a single notification is working fine too. The app's behavior in the future does not bother me, I just need the app to work right now. Are there any workarounds? Thanks

Comment: make the notification text different for each one and see what happens: `CharSequence text = "Your notification time is upon us. At: " + System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: The variable `notificationText` is already doing that. The last reminder is only the one working but the `notification_id` and `notificationText` being printed in the logcat are of the first reminder. Btw, I am not sure but are the classes ScheduleClient, ScheduleService, and AlarmTask capable of setting (or listening to) multiple alarms?

Comment: what version of Android is the device you are using running on?

Comment: The device is using API 23.